# How to show Unicode properly in Firefox Developer Tools?

Tags: firefox, unicode, firefox-developer-tools

Using the *Network* panel of the developer tools in Firefox Developer Edition, I want to see the response from server. The response is Unicode encoded Chinese, but it isn't shown properly within the *Response* tab.

[image: Chinese in response]

I have set the charset to "Unicode" but it doesn't work.

[image: "Unicode" charset selected]

Is there any way to solve this problem, so that the Chinese characters are displayed as expected?

Comment: does the `content-type` response-header for that request  specify the correct charset?

Comment: I suspect that the output may be binary and not Chinese. Therefore it would be good if you could post a screenshot of another browser as comparison.

Comment: @the8472 Yes, I have specify the correct charset, so I guess this problem is caused by my browser.

Comment: @SebastianZartner I am sure that the response is Chinese because when using other browser to send request I can get response like "\u1234" and I can use some tool to convert it into Chinese.

Comment: @LarryLu: the8472 meant, does the `Content-Type` response header (within the *Headers* tab of the DevTools) contain `charset=UTF-8`? Also, please post a screenshot of the other developer tools for comparison, or post a publicly accessible URL, so people can reproduce the issue.